# Declaring a method for an object using an immediate function

Tags: javascript, performance

I would like to know if there is any difference in between these two methods, learning purpose.

---

```
var myObject = {
  myMethod: function(){
    alert('Hello I am a method!')
  }
};
myObject.myMethod()
```

---

```
var myObject = { 
  myMethod: (function(){
    alert('Hello I am a method!')
  })
};
myObject.myMethod()
```

Comment: Both are the same, but I'd go with the first one, looks cleaner, less characters, no confusion with `()`.

Comment: Assuming you fix the syntax error in the 2nd, there is no difference. Consider: `x = 1`, `x = (1)`, `x = ((1))`, `x = (((..)))`, ad nauseam.

Comment: This is a non-question. Given your subject line you probably mix this up with ( function () {} () ) (the last ")" can also be in front of the "()", it is the same). But please don't just add additional () now - it would make even less sense, try reading up on the subject a bit more.

Comment: thanks guys for your clarifications, I will up vote your comments.